# How to compare a word from a file with a list of words in another file for C++?

Tags: c++, nested-loops, ifstream

So I'm having trouble grabbing a word from document1 and comparing it to the list of words in document2. So when I run the program, the first word of document1 is comparing to the list of words of document2, but the next word in document1 isn't comparing to the list in document2. I'm not sure what the problem is... Does it have something to do with the .eof() function?

```
string typedString, actualString, document1 = "A.txt", document2 = "Dictionary.txt";
ifstream observeDoc, actualDoc;

observeDoc.open(document1);
actualDoc.open(document2);

while (observeDoc.is_open())
{
    while (true)
    {
        observeDoc >> typedString;
        if (observeDoc.eof()) break;
        cout << typedString << endl;

        while (true)
        {
            actualDoc >> actualString;
            if (actualDoc.eof())
            {
                actualDoc.open(document1);
                break;
            }
            cout << '\t' << actualString << endl;
        }
    }
    if (observeDoc.eof()) break;
}

observeDoc.close();
actualDoc.close();
```

OUTPUT:

---

[image: outputDictionary]

Comment: I see no lists or comparisons in this code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go back to the beginning of the file.

you can use: `observeDoc.seekg(0,ios::beg);`

A better solution is to read all the words of the 1st file to an object from type `std::set<std::string>`, and for each word in the 2nd file check for existence in the set. In this way you move just once on each file, and no need to rewind.

```
std::set<std::string> words;
observeDoc.open(document1); 
while (observeDoc >> typedString){
   words.insert(typedString);
}
observeDoc.close();

actualDoc.open(document2);
while(actualDoc >> actualString){
   if (words.find( actualString )!= words.end()){
     //word exists in observer doc!
   }
} 
actualDoc.close();
```

Comment: I'm using namespace std. How can I use the set function?

Comment: Since actualDoc is a dictionary of words and is likely pretty large, it's probably better to read that file into the set and then iterate over observeDoc instead of the other way around.

Comment: You have to put actualDoc.clear() before the actualDoc.seekg(0, ios::beg). It worked for me! Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that actualDoc isn't resetting properly at the end of your loops. Also, your loop syntax could be way cleaner. Try this:

```
string typedString, actualString, document1 = "A.txt", document2 = "Dictionary.txt";
ifstream observeDoc, actualDoc;

observeDoc.open(document1);
actualDoc.open(document2);

// Will stop when it reads in EOF
while (observeDoc >> typedString)
{    
    while (actualDoc >> actualString)
    {
        // Do your comparisons here
    }
    actualDoc.open(document2); //reset actualDoc to start from the beginning of the file
    // or, as @SHR recommended, use observeDoc.seekg(0,ios::beg);
}

observeDoc.close();
actualDoc.close();
```

Comment: You have to close the file before you open it or else it will fail (or just use the `seekg` method).